# Adaptive Threshold and Contour Detection

Tags: opencv3.0

I'm trying to find contour from adaptive thresholded image, where as the contour is not detected properly.

Process:
1. Threshold the input image using Adaptive threshold
2. Find the contour in the image with RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE as parameter

Is this procedure correct?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what sort of results you're getting, as to whether or not you need to implement a more robust algorithm. An example of input and output could be helpful.

You could try something like this:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6642801